# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE at start of function

Tags: php

I have looked at this error all online and it mostly says that you're missing a semicolon but I cant find any missing semicolon I was hoping you guys could help me.

```
<?php // add_file.php
require 'log.php';
require 'dictionary.php';
function add_file($file = $_FILES["file"], $tags = $_POST["tags"] ){ // Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE
    $tags = explode(",", $tags);
    if ($file["error"]>0){
        log("add_file", "Error in file: ".$file["error"], "error");
        exit();
    } else {
        $file["deleted"] = false;
        $file["tags"] = $tags;
        $file["id"] = uniqid();
        $file["ext"] = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $file["name"] = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $file["tags"][] = $file["ext"];
        $file["tags"][] = $file["type"];
        $file["tags"][] = explode("/", $file["type"])[0];
        $file["date_created"] = date(DateTime::ATOM);
        if (file_exists("files/" . $file["id"].".".$file['ext'])){
            $file["id"] = uniqid();
            $file["loc"] = "files/" . $file["id"].".".$file['ext'];
            move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $file["loc"]);
            log("add_file", "Added file at: ".$file["loc"]);
        } else {
            $file["loc"] = "files/" . $file["id"].".".$file['ext'];
            move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $file["loc"]);
            log("add_file", "Added file at: ".$file["loc"]);
        }
        dict_add("dictionary.json", $file);
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can assign variables to function parameters

See : http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 3):

Optional arguments for functions must be constant expressions:

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a class member or a function call.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign "dynamic" default values in a function definition:

```
$x = 7;
function foo($y = $x) { } // wrong
function foo($y = 7) { } // ok
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this

```
function add_file($file = $_FILES["file"], $tags = $_POST["tags"] )
```

Do this instead

```
function add_file ($file = null, $tags = null) {
    if (is_null($file)) $file = $_FILES["file"];
    if (is_null($tags)) $tags = $_POST["tags"]
    // ...
}
```

Ideally you'd just pass those in when you call the function though

```
add_file($_FILES['file'], $_POST['tags']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php):

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.

The academic reason for this is that function definitions are registered before variables may even exist or especially have a chance to change.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tags = $_POST["tags"]
```

is the issue. Default's can only be defined as constant values, not referencing another variable (even a superglobal).... though array() is an accepted exception

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you pass parameters to a function in PHP. It should look like this -

```
function add_file($file, $tags){ 
  // 
}
add_file($_FILES["file"], $_POST["tags"]);
```

The names you give within the function is how you reference the variables within the function, and you pass the actual values (stuff in your `$_FILE` and `$_POST`)  while calling that function.

Your syntax kinda looks like you are trying to set default values for those parameters. In that case you would have to give an actual value and not a variable. For example -

```
function talk($words="Hello World"){
  echo $words;
}
```

You can now pass an *optional* value to the `talk()` function. What ever you pass, it'll echo the same thing out. But if you don't pass it anything - the default "Hello World" will be echoed.

```
talk("Winter Bash!"); // Output - Winter Bash!
talk(); // Output - Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a variable as the default for a function parameter. You have to use a constant expression (i.e. something that does not need to be evaluated) as the default value.